# codeigniter accessing through IP address in subfolder

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I have a backoffice module in codeigniter. ive uploaded it to a.setver.into backoffice/ folder. the server can be accessed only by IP address like http:// IP ADDRESS /~user/backoffice/ but its not working. 
ive uploaded it onto another server which can be accesses like www.domainname.com/backoffice/ and it works fine there. 
i have to make it work on the first server without editing the hosts file. 
i guess there must be a problem with segments order in the urls.

I opened the error log which sais file not found usr/local/apache/htdocs/home .
the home is the default controller.

the config bse url is set fine.

Comment: looks like your htaccess is wrong, I can't imagine your base controller is located in your htdocs folder directly.

Comment: @RickCalder: no, it's not in the htdocs folder, the system structure is the normal one for a module built on codeigniter. I dont know why does the server look after it in htdocs folder.